# Is it possible to skip the first anonymous request to a webserver?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, kerberos

On a webserver with Kerberos the client will send a request anonymously, and get a 401 status back.  Then it sends the same request again, with authentication, and now get a 200 status back.  Is it possible to set up a web application in MVC/JavaScript/etc to know that an anonymous request is futile and go stright for the user authentication request?  For a specific case I am using jQuery and AJAX that is pulling data from a server at short intervals.

UPDATE:  I want the client to know that there is no use sending an anonymous request, so it can just as well send a request with a username the first time.  Why sending an anonymous request in the first place when you absolutely know you will only get a 401 back?

Comment: I do not quite follow - you want to set up the **server** to instruct the **client** to send an auth request in the first place?

Comment: Are you using default [Authorize] attribute? how about create `CustomAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute` class

Comment: You also might want to consider using the `AllowAnonymousAttribute`.

Comment: See my update above. Also I don't want anonymous access to the server.

Comment: `I want the client to know that there is no use sending an anonymous request, so it can just as well send a request with a username the first time.` How should client know this thing without any request?

Comment: @AgentFire: Because I know it and I program the web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5507289/558018) answer, you should just use `beforeSend` callback and then add the `Authorization` header on your own.

Comment: This is it. Any idea how to setup this up with pass-through/windows authentication and not Basic?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for preemptive authentication and this is [highly discouraged](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html#d5e704). Do not send credentials unless the server challenges you otherwise you may reveal secrets to an unknown server.

Comment: Obviously. But this is on a vpn and should not be an issue.

Comment: If your client is a browser, good luck. They won't support that probably.

Answer (score 0):

### update as you don't need to allow anonymous access.

You could remove default IIS authentication module and/or add your own custom HttpModule for a specific part

```
  <location path="PathToWebApi">
    <system.web>
      <httpModules>
        <!-- default IIS HttpModules  -->
        <remove name="WindowsAuthentication"/>
        <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
        <remove name="PassportAuthentication"/>
        <remove name="RoleManager"/>
        <remove name="UrlAuthorization"/>
        <remove name="FileAuthorization"/>
        <remove name="AnonymousIdentification"/>
        <remove name="Profile"/>
        <add name="CustomAuthentication" type="Your.NameSpace.CustomAuthentication"/>
      </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
        <add name="CustomAuthentication" type="Your.NameSpace.CustomAuthentication" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      </modules>
  </location>
```

You can implement `CustomAuthentication : IHttpModule` class that inspect incoming request context and set current user identity depend on your custom logic.

```
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        //add event listener to authenticate Http request
        //context.AuthenticateRequest += new EventHandler(AuthenticateRequest); //Session is null at AuthenticateRequest state
        context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(OnPreRequestHandlerExecute);
    }
```

Comment: That wont do the thing OP asked for.

Comment: I used custom IHttpModule `PreRequestHandlerExecute` event to check incoming request access token, headers and cookies then decide whether to redirect anonymous access or response a custom JSON message for ajax request. this should serve the purpose.

Comment: I believe the MVC engine does that automatically in case the client has cookies. It is however quite bizarre why the client is lacking ones.